# Alignment in openpyxl wrap works, but not horizontal and vertical

Tags: python, openpyxl

Please check following code:

```
miki = ws['A1']
miki.value = 'TEST!"!""!"!!"!"!"!"!"!"!"!"!"!"'
miki.font = Font(bold=True)
miki.border = Border(left=Side(style='thin'),
                     right=Side(style='thin'),
                     top=Side(style='thin'),
                     bottom=Side(style='thin'))

miki.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='center', wrap_text=True)
```

here are printed parameters:

```
Parameters:
horizontal='center', wrapText=True, relativeIndent=0.0, justifyLastLine=None, shrinkToFit=None, vertical='center', indent=0.0, readingOrder=0.0, textRotation=0
```

for some reason in doesn't want to align text within cell, but it does wrap it... Is there something I don't see?

Comment: Did you found out the source of your problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Works for me, nothing wrong**.
Change your test String, so there is a way it can wrap and don't need the whole width of your cell, or increase the width of your cell at least to ~8 cm.

For instance:
    `.value = 'TEST!"!""!"!\n!"!"!"!"!"!"!\n"!"!"!"'`

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 - openpyxl:2.4.1 - LibreOffice: 4.3.3.2***